# T-SQL in SQL Server 2008 and later : standard function to escape string variable that is going into a like comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have user input coming in a parameter which then goes into a query to do a wildcard search.

Similar to:

```
DECLARE @myVariableContainingUserInput VARCHAR(50) = 'part of string';

DECLARE @myTable TABLE (column1 varchar(200));

INSERT INTO @myTable(column1) 
VALUES ('This is the whole string that contains part of string the user is looking for')

SELECT column1 
FROM @myTable 
WHERE column1 LIKE '%' + @myVariableContainingUserInput + '%'
```

In which case they get the one row.

However some times the data looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO @myTable(column1) 
VALUES ('This is the whole string that contains [part] of string the user is looking for')
```

and the user sometimes might search for

```
SET @myVariableContainingUserInput  = '[part';
```

and they would expect that to find one row containing 'This is the whole string that contains [part] of string the user is looking for'. It doesn't because [ is a special character.

I know I could escape it by using `[[]` or by for example adding a `\` and using `ESCAPE '\'` if I was the one in control of the search values. The input is coming from a .NET application and I have no way of knowing which special characters are coming in the parameter ahead of time or where they are in the string or how many they may be.

Is there a standard function or correct way of escaping characters going into a like comparison that would work in SQL Server 2008 (or a .NET function that could be used prior to the SQL statement hitting the server)? Or is my best bet to just create a list of special characters and loop though and escape them or use a regex to do the same?

I just know that doing a diy version would likely be to have more issues than without extensive testing than a tried and tested version.

I have tried looping through a list of special characters and replacing them with  [[] or by for example adding a \ and using  ESCAPE ''

But nothing that works well for different mixtures of characters coming in in different quantities or orders. The sql server 2008 in in the question because it is the minimum support version for the clients.

Comment: *"i have no way of knowing which special characters are coming in the parameter"* But you *do* know what special characters [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#pattern) supports, as there's only a few of them: `[_%` and whatever you chose as your `ESCAPE` character.

Comment: SQL Server 2008? You know that's been formally **end of life** for several years now, right? That means it no longer receives any updates: **not even critical security patches**. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.

Comment: Tell me about it its a right pain, our newer software has moved on to not support 2008  but this is still has some customers using that db version. Im hoping we will forcefully motivate them away soon so we can use some of the newer features of sql server.

Comment: I have initiated a conversation about dropping support for sql server 2008 which seems to have gained traction so fingers crossed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just trying to find rows where column1 contains the exact literal string entered by the user.

In that case you can do

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(@myVariableContainingUserInput, column1) > 0
```

and not have to escape anything.

You could also do

```
WHERE  column1 LIKE '%' + REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(@myVariableContainingUserInput, '[', '[[]')
                            , '%', '[%]')
                        , '_', '[_]') + '%'
```

But the `CHARINDEX` is simpler and I have greater confidence that it is correct.

Comment: Thank you.  Of the two options i like the charindex better it looks promising, I wont get a chance to test this and how it performs for a little while, but ill let you know how i get on.

Comment: For performance either way it just has to check all the (not null) strings. The leading wildcard means the LIKE can't narrow down things down any more than that either

Comment: Thank you very much, I went with the charindex option. I tried it out here on copy of real life data  on a table that had 10,000,000 rows and the results between the two were nearly the same.